# Url parameter in magento 2 collection filter

Tags: magento2, grid, model, filter, resource-model

I need to filter Magento 2 custom grid model collection by URL parameter. I have used this below code.

```
protected function _initSelect() {        

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
        $request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');  
        $seller_id = $request->getParam('seller_id');

        $this->addFilterToMap('increment_id', 'main_table.increment_id');
        $this->addFilterToMap('status', 'main_table.status');
        $this->addFilterToMap('seller_id', 'main_table.seller_id');
        $this->addFieldToFilter('seller_id', ['eq' => $seller_id]);
        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('sales_order_grid')], //2nd table name by which you want to join mail table
            'main_table.order_id = secondTable.entity_id', // common column which available in both table 
            '*' // '*' define that you want all column of 2nd table. if you want some particular column then you can define as ['column1','column2']
        )->group('main_table.order_id');    
         //$this->addFieldToFilter('main_table.seller_id', ['eq' => '39']);

        parent::_initSelect();
        // var_dump($this->getSelect()->__toString());
        // exit;

        return $this;        
    }
```

When I log this seller_id it is showing by when I pass in filter not working. it is working when I pass a static value. I'm not sure how to filter a collection by param in the model.

Answer (score 0):

`parent::_initSelect();` should be called on  start of  `_initSelect`.

**Code might look like:**

```
    protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();

    $tableDescription = $this->getConnection()->describeTable($this->getMainTable());
    foreach ($tableDescription as $columnInfo) {
        $this->addFilterToMap($columnInfo['COLUMN_NAME'], 'main_table.' . $columnInfo['COLUMN_NAME']);
    }

    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('sales_order_grid')], //2nd table name by which you want to join mail table
        'main_table.order_id = secondTable.entity_id', // common column which available in both table
        '*' // '*' define that you want all column of 2nd table. if you want some particular column then you can define as ['column1','column2']
    );
    $this->getSelect()->group('main_table.order_id');
    // Add your fiter after join
    return $this;
}
```